# Python: array[x] in O(1) complexity - shall I use Dictionary or List?

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary

As far as I know, in Python, there is no array data structure; the most intuitive solution that most of people often use is the Python list.

The question is, whether the Python list is implemented well enough to enable `O(1)` access to the 10,000th item in the list?

What is better to do for performance? Shall I use `dict` or `list`?

Comment: List access by index and dictionary access by key are both `O(1)` in the average case - see https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity. If you will have values for all 10,000 indices, a `list` makes more sense; if it will be sparse, the dictionary may use less space.

Comment: Don't let the name mislead you. Python's `list` class is a dynamic array, not a linked list.

Comment: related:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/25984900/674039

Comment: This is a very important thing to know when you are about to program a tool that makes a lot of queries

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I wonder what a dict would have to look like to cause "getting an item" to become `O(n)`...

Comment: @TimPietzcker the worst case is every key's hash colliding

Comment: @jonrsharpe: It's not going to be easy to construct such a dict, I guess :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker if you made every key be an object which returns the same hash (easy to do by defining `__hash__` on your own class) you would get an O(n) dict :)

Comment: @wim: Right, that would be a nice shortcut into inefficiency...

Comment: It's also easy to do with integers, since they hash to themselves.

Comment: No its not easy with integers because you can only have unique keys

Comment: @user3322273 "This is a very important thing to know" - it's also extremely obvious to everybody who knows how a HashMap and an Array works (and everybody who does not know this should read up on these concepts). Then the question simply becomes: do you need any keys at all, and if yes, are these keys an uniform range of numbers? Use a list(Array). If you need other keys, use a dict(HashMap). Of course the HashMap has an overhead, at least due to the hash function, and also due to hash collisions. Again, this is all completely obvious for anybody fammiliar with these data structures.

Comment: @TimPietzcker depends on [Choosing a good hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Choosing_a_good_hash_function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`list` is a bit of a misnomer: internally, Python's `list` is an array and not a linked list.

Being an array, `list` offers constant-time access by index.

Comment: IMHO, Python's array and bytearray types are arrays (which exhibit the characteristic that the values are stored in order; Python lists store references), and list is a more generic term than linked list. For instance the wikipedia articles on the subject agree.

Comment: @YannVernier: I think we're splitting hairs. I see it all the time that when someone sees the word "list", they assume a linked list (this question is one such example). I personally think it's not an unreasonable assumption, and is certainly a common one.

Answer (score 1):

I made a little benchmark and got into a conclusion that **List** works faster.

Here is the benchmark I've made:

**Running with list: 198sec user time:**

```
> time python /tmp/python_benchmark.py list
finished_building
198.816u 0.036s 3:18.97 99.9%   0+0k 0+0io 0pf+0w
```

**Running with dictionary: 211sec user time:**

```
> time python /tmp/python_benchmark.py dict
finished_building
211.065u 0.044s 3:31.19 99.9%   0+0k 0+8io 0pf+0w
```

I've printed the `finished building` string, to know how much approx. seconds it took to build the data structure, before starting to run the queries. In both times, it took less that 1 second.

This is the content of the benchmark script:

```
import sys
from random import randrange

NUM_OF_ITEMS = 100000
NUM_OF_ACCESSES = 200000000
data_structure = None

def exit_usage():
    print "Usage: python_benchmark.py <list | dict>"
    sys.exit(1)

def access_data_structure():
    for i in xrange(NUM_OF_ACCESSES):
        rnd_index = randrange(NUM_OF_ITEMS)
        dummy_assignment = data_structure[rnd_index]

if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    exit_usage()

work_type = sys.argv[1]
if work_type != 'list' and work_type != 'dict':
    exit_usage()

if work_type == 'list':
    data_structure = []
else:
    data_structure = {}

if work_type == 'list':
    for i in xrange(NUM_OF_ITEMS):
        data_structure.append(i)
else:
    for i in xrange(NUM_OF_ITEMS):
        data_structure[i] = i

print 'finished_building'

access_data_structure()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are actually several array data types in Python; `list` is an array of object references, as is `tuple`, while `bytearray` and `array.array` are numeric arrays with specific types and range checks (more generic ones, including multidimensional, are added by NumPy), and aside from tuple these are all dynamic.

`dict` is a hash table, which is a more complex data type useful primarily when keys are disorganized but hashable and the mapping is queried many times. Its keys are unordered and may be non-numeric.

What the standard library doesn't have, however, is a linked list type. The `collections.deque` type exhibits the fast end access of a doubly linked list, though insertions in the middle require memory copies (but not linear scans). There are of course addon modules with linked lists also, such as [llist](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/llist/0.4).